# Some Database Fatal Error

Tags: php, mysql, database, smarty

I want to install php code with XAMPP. I created new database and called it s13. After that i have pasted my all codes to the folder s13.

**this what I actually recieving error**

`Fatal error: Call to a member function __() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\s13\content\themes\default\templates_c\90f81337a2395d597b1b2483c3c3bf40f723241a.file.header.tpl.php on line 199`

**My config php code**

```
<?php 

define('DB_NAME', 's13')
;

define('DB_USER', 'root');

define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

define('DEBUGGING', true);

?>
```

**and this what i actually recieving error code**

```
<body page="{$page}" ub="{$userArray.Blocked}">

    <!-- Common JS -->
    <script>var SITE_URL = '{$SITE_URL}/';</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$SITE_URL}/js/core.common.js"></script>
    <!-- Common JS -->

    {if $userExist}

        <!-- Common [User Exist] JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{$SITE_URL}/js/core.common.signedin.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{$SITE_URL}/js/core.chat.js"></script>
        <!-- Common [User Exist] JS -->

        {if $userArray.Verified == "N"}
            <!-- Verify Bar -->
            <div class="verifyBarHolder">
                <div class="verifyBar">
                    <div class="verifyBarContent">
                        <div class="right">
                            <span class="uiButtonText black resendEmail">{$translate->__("Resend Confirmation Email")}</span> · <span class="uiButtonText black changeEmail">{$translate->__("Change Email Address")}</span>
                        </div>
                        {$userArray.UserFirstName}, {$translate->__("go to")} <strong>{$userArray.UserEmail}</strong> {$translate->__("to complete the sign-up process")}.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Verify Bar -->
        {/if}

        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="headerBarHolder">
            <div class="headerBar {if $userArray.Verified == "N"}afterVerify{/if}">
                <div class="header">

                    <!-- Logo -->
                    <div class="logo"><a href="{$SITE_URL}/home.php"><span>{$translate->__("Home")}</span></a></div>
                    <!-- Logo -->

                    <!-- Search -->
                    <div class="search">
                        <form id="searchForm" class="relative" action="{$SITE_URL}/search.php" method="get">
                            <span class="glass"><i></i></span>
                            <input class="uiInput searchInput" type="text" name="q" value="{$translate->__("Search")}" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Search -->

                    <!-- Navigation -->
                    <div class="navigation">
                        <ul class="list">

                            <li class="item" title="{$translate->__("Home")}">
                                <a class="navApp homeIcon" href="{$SITE_URL}/home.php"></a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="item">
                                <div class="icon relative">
                                    <div class="navApp profileIcon" id="profileIcon"></div>
                                    <!-- Profile Menu -->
                                    <div class="subMenu toRight navigationMenu">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a class="menuItem" href="{$SITE_URL}/{$userArray.UserName}">{$translate->__("Profile")}</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="menuItem" href="{$SITE_URL}/settings/">{$translate->__("Settings")}</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Profile Menu -->
                                </div>
                            </li>

                            <li class="item">
                                <div class="icon relative">
                                    <div class="navApp messagesIcon" id="messagesIcon"><span class="counter hidden" id="msgCounter"></span></div>
                                    <!-- Messages Menu -->
                                    <div class="subMenu toRight navigationMenu">
                                        <ul class="navMenu" id="liveMessages">
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="navMenuTitle">
                                                    <div class="right">
                                                        <a href="{$SITE_URL}/messages/">{$translate->__("See All")}</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <strong>{$translate->__("Messages")}</strong>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Messages Menu -->
                                </div>
                            </li>

                            <li class="item">
                                <div class="icon relative">
                                    <div class="navApp notificationsIcon" id="notificationsIcon"><span class="counter hidden" id="notifiCounter"></span></div>
                                    <!-- Notifications Menu -->
                                    <div class="subMenu toRight navigationMenu">
                                        <ul class="navMenu" id="liveNotifications">
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="navMenuTitle">
                                                    <div class="right">
                                                        <a href="{$SITE_URL}/notifications/">{$translate->__("See All")}</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <strong>{$translate->__("Notifications")}</strong>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Notifications Menu -->
                                </div>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Navigation -->

                    <!-- Sign Out -->
                    <div class="signOut">
                        <a class="navApp signoutIcon right" href="{$SITE_URL}/signout/" title="{$translate->__("Log Out")}"></a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Sign Out -->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Header -->

    {else}

        <!-- Common [User Non-Exist] JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{$SITE_URL}/js/core.common.unsignedin.js"></script>
        <!-- Common [User Non-Exist] JS -->

        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="headerBarHolder userNonExist">
            <div class="headerBar userNonExist">
                <div class="header">

                    <!-- Logo -->
                    <div class="logo userNonExist"><a href="{$SITE_URL}"><span>{$translate->__("Home")}</span></a></div>
                    <!-- Logo -->

                    <!-- Search -->
                    <div class="search userNonExist">
                        <form id="searchForm" class="relative" action="{$SITE_URL}/search.php" method="get">
                            <span class="glass"><i></i></span>
                            <input class="uiInput searchInput" type="text" name="q" value="{$translate->__("Search")}" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Search -->

                    {if $page != "signin"}
                        <!-- Sign In -->
                        <div class="signIn">
                            <div class="relative">
                                <span>{$translate->__("Have an account?")}<a class="signInBox ml5" href="{$SITE_URL}/signin/"><span>{$translate->__("Sign in")}</span></a></span>
                                <div id="signInMenu" class="signInMenu">
                                    <form action="{$SITE_URL}/signin/" method="post">
                                        <div class="inline mb10 pt10 pb10" style="width: 210px; border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;">
                                            <div class="left pt5 mr10">
                                                <span>{$translate->__("Sign in with")}</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="left">
                                                <a class="connect-facebook-vsmall" title="{$translate->__("Sign in with")} Facebook" href="{$SITE_URL}/connect/facebook/"></a> <a class="connect-twitter-vsmall" title="{$translate->__("Sign in with")} Twitter" href="{$SITE_URL}/connect/twitter/"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="mb10">
                                            <label class="inputLabel" for="username_email">{$translate->__("Username or email")}:</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="username_email" tabindex="1" />
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="mb10">
                                            <label class="inputLabel" for="email">{$translate->__("Password")}:</label>
                                            <input type="password" name="password" tabindex="2" />
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="mb10 pb10" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;">
                                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="{$translate->__("Sign in")}" class="uiButton pr10 pl10" tabindex="4" />
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember" value="yes" tabindex="3"/>
                                            <label for="remember">{$translate->__("Remember me")}</label>
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="mb5"><a href="{$SITE_URL}/recover/">{$translate->__("Forgot your password?")}</a></p>
                                        <p><a href="{$SITE_URL}/signup/">{$translate->__("Create a new account")}</a></p>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Sign In -->
                    {/if}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Header -->

    {/if}
```

Comment: Please replicate the text of the error message here instead of a screenshot. That's unreadable.

Comment: @deceze if you open image to new page it will be good...

Comment: Why do I have to open anything to a new page to see an error message? There's nothing inherently screenshot worthy in there, the text as text would serve you a lot better here.

Answer (score 1):

The error means, that at least one of variables assigned to Smarty is not an object for example maybe `$translate` is not an object. It is not connected directly to Database

Of course database has nothing in common with folders, so I have no idea why you wrote that you created database s13 and put all your data to s13 folder. Database and foldername where you have files on your server can be different.

Comment: You should chuck [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2) up as I'm almost certain OP is using wordpress ( the `__()` function)

Comment: ` Database and foldername where you have files on your server can be different.` what do you mean by this ?

Comment: @Tukhsanov I can have databae with name `my_database` and store PHP files in `my_files` directory